# How to lookup time within a duration and return another column value?

Tags: r

I have two large datasets, one named `Shifts` that contains the start and end times of individuals (`ID`) over rotations within a shift. A small example of how the data is structured:

```
> head(Shifts, 15)
     ID     Shift    Rotation     Start                 End
1       A      S1        1 2017-04-23 00:05:58 2017-04-23 00:24:40
2       A      S2        2 2017-04-23 00:00:00 2017-04-23 00:10:08
3       A      S2        3 2017-04-23 00:15:13 2017-04-23 00:27:32
4       A      S3        4 2017-04-23 00:00:00 2017-04-23 00:20:43
5       A      S3        5 2017-04-23 00:27:49 2017-04-23 00:33:28
6       A      S4        6 2017-04-23 00:04:26 2017-04-23 00:31:37
7       B      S1        1 2017-04-23 00:00:00 2017-04-23 00:11:56
8       B      S1        2 2017-04-23 00:13:42 2017-04-23 00:29:10
9       B      S2        3 2017-04-23 00:03:38 2017-04-23 00:24:28
10      B      S3        4 2017-04-23 00:00:00 2017-04-23 00:27:36
11      B      S3        5 2017-04-23 00:31:08 2017-04-23 00:33:28
12      B      S4        6 2017-04-23 00:00:01 2017-04-23 00:14:26
13      B      S4        7 2017-04-23 00:18:32 2017-04-23 00:31:37
14      C      S1        1 2017-04-23 00:00:00 2017-04-23 00:29:10
15      C      S2        2 2017-04-23 00:00:00 2017-04-23 00:19:28
```

The other dataset `(Activities)` contains timestamped work activities (`Symbol`) completed by individuals `(ID)` over each shift. A small example of this dataset:

```
  > head(Activity, 10)
   ID    Symbol Shift         Time
1  B     TE      S1 2017-04-23 00:00:22
2  B     TI      S1 2017-04-23 00:00:24
3  C     TE      S1 2017-04-23 00:01:08
4  A     TE      S1 2017-04-23 00:06:08
5  B     TE      S1 2017-04-23 00:01:25
6  B      P      S1 2017-04-23 00:01:33
7  C      P      S1 2017-04-23 00:01:36
8  C      T      S1 2017-04-23 00:01:36
9  A      T      S1 2017-04-23 00:07:45
10 A      T      S1 2017-04-23 00:08:25
```

For each ID over every shift, I now wish to look up if `Activities$Time` within the time interval `Shifts$Start` and `Shifts$End` then return the corresponding `Shift$Rotation` column. My anticipated output would be:

```
  > head(Activity, 10)
   ID    Symbol Shift         Time       Rotation
1  B     TE      S1 2017-04-23 00:00:22       1 
2  B     TI      S1 2017-04-23 00:00:24       1
3  C     TE      S1 2017-04-23 00:01:08       1 
4  A     TE      S1 2017-04-23 00:06:08       1 
5  B     TE      S1 2017-04-23 00:01:25       1
6  B      P      S1 2017-04-23 00:01:33       1
7  C      P      S1 2017-04-23 00:01:36       1
8  C      T      S1 2017-04-23 00:01:36       1
9  A      T      S1 2017-04-23 00:07:45       1
10 A      T      S1 2017-04-23 00:08:25       1
```

As both datasets are quite large, with many ID's, Shifts and Rotations, is there a quick way to lookup and return this column as per the above?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

Activity <- inner_join(Shifts, Activities, by = c("ID", "Shift")) %>%
  mutate(
    temp = (Start < Time) * (Time < End)
  ) %>%
  filter(temp == 1) %>%
  select(ID, Symbol, Shift, Time, Rotation)
```

Comment: Thanks, however I am getting the following error message: `Joining, by = c("ID", "Shift", "Start", "End")
Warning messages:
1: All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 
2: All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 
3: All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 
4: All formats failed to parse. No formats found. `

Comment: @user2716568 What class are the time columns (i.e. `class(Shifts$Start)`)?  I think that is the source of the error.

Comment: The classes of the time columns are: `> class(Shifts$Start)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
> class(Shifts$End)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
> class(IActivities$Time)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"`

Comment: @user2716568 I edited the code.  I think it should work without the calls to `ymd_hms()`.  I also added the `by` argument to `inner_join()`.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the edits and your time in answering my question :-)